# Hadoop setting the HADOOP_HOME correctly to bin/hadoop it gives command not found

Tags: hadoop

After installing hadoop and  setting up HADOOP_HOME to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop and when running hadoop by just typing hadoop in terminal, it says that I don't have privileges. Then I tried running it with sudo then it says that, sudo : command not found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `HADOOP_HOME` should point to `/usr/local/hadoop`.
2. If you want to type just `hadoop` in terminal, you have to add it in Global path variable. To do, add these lines in `/home/hadoopuser/.bashrc`:

   `export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop`

   `export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin`

> **NOTE: hadoopuser** is your hadoop username. Replace it with your username.

Comment: Thanks, now it works fine. but when I tried to run example in the share directory of hadoop it says permission denied

Comment: What example did you try?

Comment: examples in the share directory of hadoop, mapreduce word count one

Comment: Its actualy hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.0.jar

Comment: I am not asking which jar you tried to run. Just post the command you tried like `hadoop jar ...`. Your error might be due to wrong permission on input folder.

Comment: hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/ hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.0.jar

Comment: Your command is not full. You wont get any result with this command. Try this http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount. This link shows how to run a wordcount example.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines in ~/.bash_profile, if you are using Mac OS;

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/karanverma/Documents/backups/h/hadoop-2.6.4
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/Users/karanverma/Documents/backups/h/hadoop-2.6.4
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar

export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH

export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/bng/Documents/mongodb/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$PATH
```